# How to move picture boxes in a panel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I'm trying to move picture boxes in a panel.

This is my Code:

```
Private dragging As Boolean
Private beginX, beginY As Integer

Private Sub Control_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        dragging = True
        beginX = CType(sender, PictureBox).Location.X
        beginY = CType(sender, PictureBox).Location.Y
End Sub

Private Sub Control_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Dim cntrl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
        If dragging = True Then
            cntrl.Location = New Point(cntrl.Location.X + e.X - beginX, cntrl.Location.Y + e.Y - beginY)
            'Me.Refresh()
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub Control_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        dragging = False
End Sub
```

I can't figure out why this don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The subroutines you have are missing their handlers (ie the `handles` statement) at the end.

ex:

```
Private Sub Control_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) HANDLES controlName.MouseUp
    dragging = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I created picture box in looping

for loop
    btn = new PictureBox

    AddHandler btn.MouseUp, AddressOf Control_MouseUp
   AddHandler btn.MouseDown, AddressOf Control_MouseDown
   AddHandler btn.MouseMove, AddressOf Control_MouseMove
   pnlLocker.Controls.Add(btn)
next

Comment: every time i clicked on picture box it blinks and when i moved the mouse the picture box doesn't change its location...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim cmd As Boolean = False     
    Dim sp As Point
    Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load 
        For Each Control As Picturebox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Picturebox)
        AddHandler Control.MouseDown, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
                                          cmd = True
                                          sp = e.Location
                                      End Sub
        AddHandler Control.MouseMove, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
                                          If cmd Then
                                              Control.Location = Control.Location - sp + e.Location
                                          End If
                                      End Sub
        AddHandler Control.MouseUp, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
                                        cmd = False
                                    End Sub 
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you could say a little bit about your Code that other understand and don't just copy.